# Preferred ROS XML parser/generator

Tags: xml

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would like to create a node/library that both reads in xml and writes xml with a well defined format (sort of like URDF).  I know there are tons of libraries for doing this, but I want to know what are the preferred libraries to use with ROS in either C++ or Python?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/58046/preferred-ros-xml-parser/generator/) by [sedwards](https://answers.ros.org/users/78/sedwards/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1601 on 2013-03-13

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Here are some quick examples I found:

- TinyXML for C++ (in [urdf_parser.h](https://github.com/ros-gbp/urdfdom-release/blob/debian/groovy/urdfdom/urdf_parser/include/urdf_parser/urdf_parser.h) and [srdf](https://github.com/ros/robot_model/blob/groovy-devel/srdf/package.xml))
- minidom for python (in [roslaunch](http://ros.org/doc/groovy/api/roslaunch/html/) and [urdf_parser_py](http://www.ros.org/wiki/urdf_parser_py))
- BeautifulSoup for python (in [ur5_driver](http://ros.org/rosdoclite/groovy/api/ur5_driver/html/driver_8py_source.html))

---

Originally posted by [Jeremy Zoss](https://answers.ros.org/users/3925/jeremy-zoss/) with karma: 4976 on 2013-03-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2